# check how many times a column of an array is equal to a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an image converted with the use of im2cal in an array of 9 rows and 3867208 columns and i want to count how many times a vector containing a mask is equal to each column of the image without using for loops in matlab.Do you have any ideas?

Comment: look into `ismember` ...

Comment: Interesting question, but it would be better to provide an example. Is the mask a column vector consisting of 9 rows? Is the mask a column vector of, say, 2 rows and thus can be found multiple times within the same column?